# Delete desde una validación

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola tengo un conflicto al tratar de hacer un delete, parece ser por un tema de fK `DELETE  FROM "V2_DM"."CARGA_IVR" USING "V2_DM"."IVR" WHERE "IVR"."FK_IdCargaIVR" isnull and "CARGA_IVR"."IdCargaIVR"  notnull ;`

esta es la respuesta de error que me muestra: ERROR:  update or delete on table "CARGA_IVR" violates foreign key constraint "FK_IdCargaIVR" on table "IVR"
DETAIL:  Key (IdCargaIVR)=(39481) is still referenced from table "IVR".
SQL state: 23503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando está utilizando una base de datos relacional, estás configurando entidades con relaciones entre estas entidades.

**El error que estás recibiendo significa que:**

Estás intentando eliminar un registro cuya clave primaria funciona como foreing key en otra tabla, **por lo que no puede eliminarlo.**

Para eliminar ese registro, **primero elimine el registro con la clave externa** y **luego elimina el original que deseas eliminar.**

link que te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576191